# Decrypt Base64 string with RSA private key

Tags: java, node.js

I have an encrypted string with RSA public key, and I need to decrypt a string with RSA private key.

I have already a working Java code, but I need to write a similar code with Node.js library to decrypt my message.

Here is the working Java code,

```
public static String getDecrypted(String data, String Key) 
      throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
      PrivateKey pk = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(
          new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(Key.getBytes())));
      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pk);
      byte[] encryptedbytes = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(data.getBytes()));
      return new String(encryptedbytes);
}
```

I could not find the respective node.js code for the same.

I have a Base64 encoded string, like below

`S+JnXECfe8zHO69Mp0oh6ux******.......`

And having the private key as below,

`MIIJQgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCC*****............`

I could not get the similar code in node.js with crypto module. Since, I am new to this crypto module, I am not sure if the code I am trying is correct,

```
//decryption

const crypto = require('crypto');

const PK_HEADER = '\n-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n'
const PK_FOOTER = '\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n'

const pkey ='MIIJQgIBADANBgkqhki......'

const privateKey = `${PK_HEADER}${pkey}${PK_FOOTER}`
const privateEncodedKey = Buffer.from(privateKey, 'base64')

const response = "0f8c396c5279a...";
const decrypt = (privateEncodedKey, message) => {
let enc = crypto.privateDecrypt({
key: privateEncodedKey,
padding: crypto.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING
}, Buffer.from(message, 'hex'));
return enc.toString();
};

console.log(decrypt(privateEncodedKey, response ))
```

Can you help us modify the code in node.js crypto?

Here is the details to decrypt..

Algorithm    RSA (Rivest–Shamir–Adleman)
Mode    ECB (Electronic Codebook)
Padding    OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the exact equivalent code in node.js for the above Java code.

`````````
var crypto = require("crypto");
var path = require("path");
var fs = require("fs");

var encryptStringWithRsaPublicKey = function(toEncrypt, relativeOrAbsolutePathToPublicKey) {
    var absolutePath = path.resolve(relativeOrAbsolutePathToPublicKey);
    var publicKey = fs.readFileSync(absolutePath, "utf8");
    var buffer = Buffer.from(toEncrypt);
    var encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt(publicKey, buffer);
    return encrypted.toString("base64");
};

var decryptStringWithRsaPrivateKey = function(toDecrypt, relativeOrAbsolutePathtoPrivateKey) {
    var absolutePath = path.resolve(relativeOrAbsolutePathtoPrivateKey);
    var privateKey = fs.readFileSync(absolutePath, "utf8");
    var buffer = Buffer.from(toDecrypt, "base64");
    console.log("PRIVATE_KEY:",privateKey);
    var decrypted = crypto.privateDecrypt({
        key: privateKey,
        padding:crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING
    }, buffer);

    return decrypted.toString("utf8");
};`

cipher= '/**Encrypted TEXT/*'

/*private.pem*/
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
............................
-----ENDPRIVATE KEY-----
/**/
const decryptedText = decryptStringWithRsaPrivateKey(cipher,'private.pem')
````````
`````````

Answer (score 1):

Meta: I'm amazed this isn't a dupe, but I can't find one.

First, if your data is in fact encrypted with OAEP, that Java code should *not* work. `PKCS1Padding` in Java (and most other places) is specifically *PKCSv1.5* padding, now retronymed `RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5` for encryption (and `RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5` for signature, not applicable here). Although OAEP is also defined in PKCS1v2.0 up, in Java you should specify just `OAEPPadding` for the default (which is SHA-1), or for non-defaults`OAEPwith{hash}andMGF1Padding` or else a third init argument of type `javax.crypto.spec.OAEPParameterSpec`.

Second, the base64'd privatekey you showed part of is in PKCS8-unencrypted format (aka encoding), not PKCS1 format. If you got it from Java, this is expected; Java crypto uses PKCS8 format for `PrivateKey` for all algorithms, (and "X.509" format for `PublicKey`). This is documented in a somewhat unobvious place, [the superinterface `Key`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Key.html). The correct **PEM type for PKCS8-unencrypted is `PRIVATE KEY`** -- not `RSA PRIVATE KEY` which is for PKCS1.

**Also,** PEM files are not just BEGIN line, *one* base64 line, and END line. They are BEGIN line, one or more base64 line(s) **broken every 64 characters**, and END line. nodejs uses OpenSSL, older versions of which enforced a slight relaxation of this restriction; they allowed up to 76 characters per line. Newer versions allow much more, but there is still a limit and I believe your key (apparently 4096-bit or close) may exceed it, and thus will not work without at least some linebreaks added.

Finally, once you have PEM format, do *not* base64-decode it. That will include the BEGIN and END lines in the decoding, totally garbaging the result. This part (and several others) of **nodejs crypto traditionally accepts the same PEM format OpenSSL does**; according to the doc 11.6.0 up can accept an alternate form using OpenSSL's 'DER' format, which does correspond to base64 decoding the actual key data NOT the whole PEM (but I don't have a version that new to test on).

Thus, here is an example (using *my* key and data) of both methods that should work, assuming you are correct about using OAEP:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const pk8b64 = (
"MIICdgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAmAwggJcAgEAAoGBAKNwapOQ6rQJHetP"+
"HRlJBIh1OsOsUBiXb3rXXE3xpWAxAha0MH+UPRblOko+5T2JqIb+xKf9Vi3oTM3t"+
"KvffaOPtzKXZauscjq6NGzA3LgeiMy6q19pvkUUOlGYK6+Xfl+B7Xw6+hBMkQuGE"+
"nUS8nkpR5mK4ne7djIyfHFfMu4ptAgMBAAECgYA+s0PPtMq1osG9oi4xoxeAGikf"+
"JB3eMUptP+2DYW7mRibc+ueYKhB9lhcUoKhlQUhL8bUUFVZYakP8xD21thmQqnC4"+
"f63asad0ycteJMLb3r+z26LHuCyOdPg1pyLk3oQ32lVQHBCYathRMcVznxOG16VK"+
"I8BFfstJTaJu0lK/wQJBANYFGusBiZsJQ3utrQMVPpKmloO2++4q1v6ZR4puDQHx"+
"TjLjAIgrkYfwTJBLBRZxec0E7TmuVQ9uJ+wMu/+7zaUCQQDDf2xMnQqYknJoKGq+"+
"oAnyC66UqWC5xAnQS32mlnJ632JXA0pf9pb1SXAYExB1p9Dfqd3VAwQDwBsDDgP6"+
"HD8pAkEA0lscNQZC2TaGtKZk2hXkdcH1SKru/g3vWTkRHxfCAznJUaza1fx0wzdG"+
"GcES1Bdez0tbW4llI5By/skZc2eE3QJAFl6fOskBbGHde3Oce0F+wdZ6XIJhEgCP"+
"iukIcKZoZQzoiMJUoVRrA5gqnmaYDI5uRRl/y57zt6YksR3KcLUIuQJAd242M/WF"+
"6YAZat3q/wEeETeQq1wrooew+8lHl05/Nt0cCpV48RGEhJ83pzBm3mnwHf8lTBJH"+
"x6XroMXsmbnsEw=="
) .replace(/.{64}/g,"$&\n");

const ctxb64 =
"QLiNLbAqDPG024Xdtl80OMWCHfPq4pCIduoXKcVyY0211Ji7n6Cvjp+ATyLg95mX"+
"/xuFdLV6jiR0ayVw1KTb+U3WKwQRsAWzA+gYiDjdfRaCrNxtcCp2Onw92bjdjZke"+
"O7VrmzDj+8ovDvDgb/pXhAPMcJKSCDUVXgCxpZSnVJE=";
const ctxbuf = Buffer.from(ctxb64,'base64');

// the traditional way 
const t1 = crypto.privateDecrypt("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n"+pk8b64+"\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n", ctxbuf);
console.log(t1);

// should work in 11.6.0 (not tested); can add padding: to specify if other than OAEP 
const t2 = crypto.privateDecrypt({key:Buffer.from(pk8b64,'base64'),format:'der',type:'pkcs8'}, ctxbuf);
console.log(t2);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.  Your code is working fine with the latest node js. But When I execute with my private key and text, I am getting the below error.

internal/crypto/cipher.js:53
    return method(data, format, type, passphrase, buffer, padding);
           ^

Error: error:0406506C:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_private_decrypt:data greater than mod len
const t2 = crypto.privateDecrypt(
  {
    key: Buffer.from(pk8b64, "base64"),
    format: "der",
    type: "pkcs8",
    padding: crypto.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING
  },
  ctxbuf
);
console.log(t2.toString());

Comment: Sathish: then either you have a wrong ciphertext for your key (perhaps damaged in copying or transmission) or the wrong key for your ciphertext. A valid RSA ciphertext is always numerically less than the modulus value 'n' in the key, and normally represented as an octet string the same length as the modulus, which _may_ be encoded in hex, base64, or similar. (And the same for a signature.)

Comment: Hi Dave. Sorry for the late response. You are exactly correct,  it key what I am using is wrong. Your code works fine, but I can't upgrade the node to latest version. So tried the code.

Comment: @SathishKumarSundaramoorthy - Based on your comments, I think this should be marked as the correct answer?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you for your answer. Do you do any private consultation work? (Mods, apologies if that is an inappropriate question - please let me know if so and I'll take this comment down)